# Non-circular definition of orientation of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to get an intuitive grasp of the notion of orientation in a vector space. In the Euclidean plain, we would say intuitively that a basis is positively oriented if the smallest angle from $\mathbb{e_1}$ to $\mathbb{e_2}$ is counter-clockwise. Every source I've consulted formalizes this, after introducing the usual vector space machinery, by distinguishing two equivalence classes of ordered bases depending on the sign of the determinant of the transition matrix between them.

However, when I look up the intuitive construction of determinants, it turns out the determinant gives the signed area of the image of the unit square, and this sign is used to make sure we can distinguish between two different orientations. But then...isn't the entire notion of orientation completely circular?

Comment: You have to start somewhere and define something to be 'positive'. Then the circular part is making sure that notions are consistent.

Comment: It's similar to the definition of left vs. right or clockwise vs. counterclockwise. Arbitrary, but not circular.